# UE Boom 2 sound quality with laptop is awful

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, blueman

today I updated the firmware of my UE Boom 2 and ever since I noticed a huge drop in sound quality while using my laptop. My mobile phone works as fine before, but it's awful with the laptop. Any help is appreciated.

I use blueman for bluetooth.
My ubuntu release is 16.04

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when first connecting mine to my laptop.
I had to change one thing in Sound settings (Volume control) then Configuration (not sure it's the good translation, my xubuntu is not in english).
There for UE Boom, I changed "Headphones" to "High Quality ... A2DP".

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please clarify it with more details? A step by step guide would be very handy, so the OP can follow your instructions. :)

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed that exact same issue but on Mac. I am pretty sure you can fix it too using the same trick on Ubuntu as it seems to be an issue with the UE rather than the OS.

It is about the UE's microphone (input, not output). When your OS is (automatically) set to use the UE's input, the sound is awful:

[image]

However it is all great when the input is set to the internal microphone:

[image]

I guess this doc would help changing the audio input on Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-usemic.html.en